# How to use image binary data directly in kivy for widgets like icon and FloatButtons

Tags: python, image, kivy, binary-data

I have few icon pics who's binary form is stored in database . now I have few approaches:

> To take the binary data from database and covert it into a png or jpeg file and store it on the user's device

or

> To directly use the binary data without storing it on user's device

I prefer the second one . but the problem is the kivy widgets such as MDIcon or FloatButtton needs a string of address and not binary data so is their a way to resolve this .

And please let me know if their is a better way of solving this issue.

Comment: We need a bit more information. Like, where is this binary data located, what format do you want to convert it to, which module are you planning on using for doing so, etc.

Comment: Sorry brother. Firstly  I am reading an image using read method of file. Then I am storing the binary data obtained in mysql table. Then my plan is to use the data from the table and directly use it   in kivy. But I don't  have an idea to do si

Comment: Also the other i did was i converted the binary data to image using bytesio and kivy coreimage , image modules. But the problem was that I have to store the file in users device which I don't  want. So any better idea or any way to use binary data directly in kivy widgets like MdIcon

Comment: No worries! You said, you tried BytesIO. With BytesIO you don't have to store the file on the actual drive. Want me to post an example?

Comment: yep bro can u please post an example.. sry for late reply

Comment: Sure can do. Could you tell me what library you're using to convert your binary to image?

Comment: actually i am using PIL . but i also think kivy `CoreImage` is also great but we can't use `image` widget in icon path . can we?

Comment: Brother u can also show a better way if u know. For me anything will work  .plz

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Had some issues on my end yesterday. I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an image without saving it on the drive like this.

```
from io import BytesIO

def convertToJpeg(img):
    with BytesIO() as f:
        img.save(f, format='JPEG')
        return f.getvalue()
```

Comment: thanks brother, but one more help can u please give some explanation for this function ?